# Urban Terror Updater frozen

Tags: software-installation, urban-terror

I'm trying to install Urban Terror via their "Urban Terror Updater" and it's been downloading files for a while but it froze. It's not downloading any more. What can I do to make it resume?

I tried resetting my internet connection (with `sudo service network-manager restart`) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just "Quit" and run the installer again and it'll continue where it left off. Just be careful not to change the location of the installer, or the folders it creates.